# python script for downloading youtube video

Tags: python-2.7, pafy

I am trying to download a youtube video using python.Below is my code.But it is giving me ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package.Can anyone help me solving this issue.I am new to python ...Someone please help

```
  import pafy
  url = raw_input("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PT2_F-1esPk")
  video = pafy.new(url)
  t= video.title
  r = video.rating
  print t
  print r
  best = video.getbest("mp4")
  filename = best.download(quiet = False)
```

Comment: I don't know that this is allowed. Also, please format code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
url = raw_input("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PT2_F-1esPk")
video = pafy.new(url)
```

Just do

```
video = pafy.new("PT2_F-1esPk")
```

Initialize the video with the 11 digit id. raw_input gives back an empty string.

Comment: from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import urllib
import shutil
ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PT2_F-1esPk'])